# Ansible-AWX get file from remote Windows to local linux

Tags: linux, windows, ansible, file-transfer, ansible-awx

Hello to all stack overflow community.
I'm seeking you help because I've been trying to accomplish the task of getting a file from remote Windows to local linux using Ansible-AWX and I can't get it to work. Bellow I shared the playbook and most of tests I've done but none of them worked.

I'm getting latest file in a windows directory and trying to transfer that file to local AWX either inside the docker or in the linux server where AWX is running.

Test_1: Said file was copied but when I go inside the docker nothing there. I can't find an answer and couldn't find any on Google.

Test_2: Didn't work. It says can't authenticate to linux server

Test_3: Task became idle and I have to restart the docker to be able to stop it. It gets crazy. No idea why.

Test_4: It says connection unexpectedly closed.

I didn't want to provide output to reduce noise and because I can't share the information. I removed names and ips from playbook as well.

I'm connecting to Windows server using AD.

Please, I don't know what else to do. Thanks for your help in advance.

```
---
- name: Get file from Windows to Linux
  hosts: all # remote windows server ip
  gather_facts: true
  become: true

  vars:
    local_dest_path_test1: \var\lib\awx\public\ # Inside AWX docker
    local_dest_path_test2: \\<linux_ip>\home\user_name\temp\  # Outside AWX docker in the linux server
    local_dest_path_test3: /var/lib/awx/public/ # Inside AWX docker
    # Source file in remote windows server
    src_file: C:\temp\

  tasks:
    # Getting file information to be copied
    - name: Get files in a folder
      win_find:
        paths: "{{ src_file }}"
      register: found_files

    - name: Get latest file
      set_fact:
        latest_file: "{{ found_files.files | sort(attribute='creationtime',reverse=true) | first }}"

    # Test 1
    - name: copy files from Windows to Linux
      win_copy:
        src: "{{ latest_file.path }}"
        dest: "{{ local_dest_path_test1 }}"
        remote_src: yes

    # Test 2
    - name: copy files from Windows to Linux
      win_copy:
        src: "{{ latest_file.path }}"
        dest: "{{ local_dest_path_test2 }}"
        remote_src: yes
      become: yes
      become_method: su
      become_flags: logon_type=new_credentials logon_flags=netcredentials_only
      vars:
        ansible_become_user: <linux_user_name>
        ansible_become_pass: <linux_user_password>
        ansible_remote_tmp: <linux_remote_path>

    # Test 3
    - name: Fetch latest file to linux
      fetch:
        src: "{{ latest_file.path }}"
        dest: "{{ local_dest_path_test3 }}"
        flat: yes
        fail_on_missing: yes
      delegate_to: 127.0.0.1

    # Test 4
    - name: Transfer file from Windows to Linux
      synchronize:
        src: "{{ latest_file.path }}"
        dest: "{{ local_dest_path_test3 }}"
        mode: pull
      delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
```